# Can someone tell me what i might be doing wrong

Tags: .net, vb.net

Ok I am edited this. This is what i have so far.
Option Strict On
Option Explicit On

Module Module1

```
Sub Main()
    Dim numberofdays As Integer
    Dim month As Integer
    Dim year As Integer

    Select Case month
        Case 4, 6, 9, 11
            numberofdays = 30
        Case 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 10, 12
            numberofdays = 31
        Case 2
            Select Case year
                Case 2004, 2008, 2012, 2016
                    numberofdays = 29
                Case Else
                    numberofdays = 28
            End Select
    End Select
    Console.WriteLine("Please enter your month")
    Console.ReadLine()
End Sub
```

End Module
Now i get it to come up but when you type in 3 nothing comes up i have tried putting in the writeline( this month has 31 days in it) but still nothing can someone tell me what i am doing wrong. I am working with select case. I am still new to this so I am not that far in advance thanks.

Comment: What is the error you are getting.  The more specific you make your question, the more likely you will get an answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to call `numberofdays` as if it were a method, like this:

```
numberofdays(31)
```

I suspect you meant to assign the value to the variable, like this:

```
numberofdays = 31
```

You're also trying to use `month` and `year` without giving them values first. Which month are you interested in, and which year? If you're interested in the *current* month and year, you might want to use:

```
Dim now As DateTime = DateTime.Now
Dim month as Integer = now.Month
Dim year as Integer = now.Year
```

Note that if this isn't just to experiment with the language, you should look at [`DateTime.DaysInMonth`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.daysinmonth.aspx).

Comment: Damn it, why are you so quick?

Comment: well both cause February can go to either 28 or 29 days depends on the year.

Comment: @sha: What do you mean by "well both"? You need to decide which month and year you're interested in, otherwise what do you expect it to print? *You haven't given `month` and `year` values.*

Comment: Well i know most months are 31 and then some are 30 but February is a little hard to do because depending on the year you can have either 28 or 29 days so to me month 2 is harder to put in. That's why i have the case else in there.

Comment: @sha: You're missing my point. Your code will do different things depending on the values of `month` and `year`. That's fine... but you have to actually *provide* the values for `month` and `year`, otherwise the code has no way of telling what it's meant to work with! It's like asking a tax program to work out your taxes but without telling it how much you've earned...

Comment: Ok sorry i am not trying to miss the point just trying to understand it better.

Comment: @sha: So do you understand the point now? By the way, you're never *using* `numberofdays` after you've assigned it a value. You could remove all the `Console.WriteLine` calls and put *one* call underneath the `End Select` line, to print out the value of `numberofdays`.

Comment: Yeah I am trying to do what you suggested but its not turning out.

Comment: @sha: Then edit your question with the amended code (ideally keeping the original - add a section at the bottom starting with "EDIT" to make it clear what's going on).

Answer (score 0):

`numberofdays(31)` should be `numberofdays = 31` and same for when it is 30 days

Answer (score 0):

To add to what everyone else has said, you need to fix the following line too:

Select Case year()

This should be

Select Case year

(no brackets).

Comment: I got rid of the bracket they are not longer there. I just can not get the output i am needing to do.